# access DOM element by ID without API

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I've encountered a funny thing recently when I try to access the DOM element by id. So, let me show you what I got.

Here is the HTML code:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
    <ul id='here' data-hi='123'>
        <li id='li1'>1</li>
        <li id='li2'>2</li>
        <li id='li3'>3</li>
    </ul>
</body>
</html>
```

I try to access the second list item with the id "li2" and remove it, here is the JavaScript code:

```
var ul = document.getElementById('here');
ul.removeChild(li2);
```

Obviousely, the "li1" is not defined before it's been used. However, this code works, the seconde item in the list was removed.

than, I try another code like this:

```
here.removeChild(li2);
```

It's still working!!! I try to run this code on Chrome44, Firefox40 and IE11, the code worked fine on these browser.

Then I tried to give the second li tag a name called "li2name", and did the same thing:

```
<li id='li2' name='li2name'>2</li>

here.removeChild(li2name);
```

An error was throwed:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: li2name is not defined
```

My question is why it works when I try to access the element directly with a object name after the ID of the element? Dose the JavaScript engine invoke the document.getElementById implicitly for us?

Comment: It's by design. ID's are mapped right into the `window` object for backward compatibility. It's one of the old dark sides of JS :)

Comment: `name` on a LI (DIV, etc) element is invalid. So, I hope you have your answer. For more info on the `name` attr: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/name

Comment: Thank you all guys, I found my answer according to the [Do DOM tree elements with ids become global variables?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3434278/do-dom-tree-elements-with-ids-become-global-variables). I looked into the window object, and found the some property with the name "here" "li2", and `console.log("here" in window)` did output `true`. Thank you all for helping me get the answer.